# Windows Boot Manager the only option to boot from

Tags: boot, bios

I tried to install Ubuntu Mate and everything worked fine during the live installation. I was able to see the hard disk with df -h. After the reboot once installation was complete, I couldn't boot from the hard disk as it did not show up in the BIOS. Now I installed Windows 10 and I am able to boot from Windows Boot Manager which is the only option. I want to install Ubuntu. Any idea?

Comment: You've provided no release details; are you hoping we guess?  If the ISO is written to media (thumb-drive etc) incorrectly using a *reformat* option (not *clone*), it's possible for the boot system to fail to install (ie. you can't boot into your *new install*), but you gave no details of how you wrote your *unstated release* ISO, but this is **not** the only potential pitfall.

Comment: @guiverc I can boot from usb stick with Ubuntu live installation. I install the the os, then after reboot I get only Windows Boot Manager. This happens with other systems such Lubuntu.

Comment: All Ubuntu *flavors* are just Ubuntu Desktop systems built with different *seeds* which cause different packages to be used; so Ubuntu-MATE, Lubuntu & Ubuntu Desktop are to me the same (Lubuntu uses a different installer, as does Ubuntu Desktop for 23.04, but you've not said what release & to me installer changes little). You can, by using a *reformat* of ISO when writing to media, cause the installer (both `ubiquity` of Ubuntu MATE & `calamares` of Lubuntu) install the boot records to the wrong drive; this is not the flaw of the installer; it was tricked by the Operator writing ISO wrongly

Comment: If the ISO is written as is documented (for all Ubuntu products; using a simple *clone* without re-format) this will not occur...  There is a bug with `ubiquity` that can cause the boot records to be written to the wrong device (*a reformat of the ISO triggers this bug! on all hardware*) that can also be triggered by specific *firmware* (ie. box specific), but you've not provided any release details so I'm stuck at being *generic* only in advice. Did you write your *unstated* ISO as per Ubuntu instructions?